# Safe shell call with php

Tags: php, shell

I have a little coding project.

I want to manage my dedicated server (debian based) with a web interface.

I want to manage for example my services, my game server etc..
I allready have scripts to control them with a ssh connection, but it comes to be a good exercise to code my own manager.

My question is How to make shell command with php. And I know there are functions to do so, but, I read that allow the www-data account all right is not safe, so is there a way to make this securely ?
(Of course my programs are all launched with a different account.)

Also I want the interface to be sustainable easily (like the possibilty to add a service  without making a lot of change).

Many Thanks.

Comment: `(Of course my programs are all launched with a different account.)` <= how?

Comment: Every programm is in his specific account. Mumble got one, minecraft too etc..

Comment: all your exec() calls are going to be done as ONE user: apache. you'd have to grant apache writes to whatever dirs/files it's going to be manipulating in each program's directories, or your run suphp and switch to the appropriate account. just be VERY careful.

Comment: @MarcB that's the problem, I was wondering if there is any secure way to do so. And I see that you can only grant specific command with the sudoers list. But if I want to add some program I have to edit this list too. Thanks for the suphp, I didn't know this library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is very general.

In php you have **exec()**  **shell_exec()**  **system()** and **passthru()** just google for them for detailed info.

All they have in common is they execute a binary file (assumed Apache (are you on Apache?)) have permissions to do so.

To avoid security issues you have to be sure on what command is executed and which parameters are passed, in any case/situation/context.

If they are 100% properly checked and validated by the code that's before the call then the code is safe.

The first thing you should care about is never let the client (communicating to the server with GET or POST requests) execute arbitrary commands or pass arbitrary parameters.

To increase security protect sesitive files and directories from the user/group Apache is running

-OR-

run Apache with a user group that is not harmful for sensitive files/directories (don't run is as root for example...)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yes the commands will be static, I think. And stored in a database so that I and only I can add some more. (And yes this is apache.)

Comment: For the moment every account is in his own group too, I don't know if this is a good way to do

Comment: Not very clear the last comment. Apache run with a defined user/group and so do the processes it launches with PHP's shell_exec and family... if the user/group have permission to execute, read, write the shell tool you invoke will act with those permissions.

Comment: Yeah I know but for example the minecraft account is in the minecraft group etc